# Reference Error: selectZIP is not defined

Tags: javascript, geoprocessing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In Firebug I keep getting this error when I try to click a button I made.

```
<button type="button" onclick="selectZIP()">Execute</button>
```

I declared a function called selectZIP in a .js file and put it in my HTML file. Yet am still having this error. SelectZIP is a geoprocessor which tries to...select ZIP codes.

```
function selectZIP(){
    gp = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor("******/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/selectZIP");
    myMap.selectZIP.setOutputSpatialReference({
        "wkid": 102100
    });
```

In my .js file I have this, before my button statement

```
<script src="js/EDDM_API - Copy.js"></script>
```

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: are you sure the js file is loaded?, maybe you click before it's loaded... you can check it on firebug... on the network section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think filenames or URLs on the web can contain spaces.

Try renaming `<script src="js/EDDM_API - Copy.js">` to `<script src="js/EDDM_API-Copy.js">` with the spaces removed.

Comment: File names can contain spaces on the web, which will become URL-encoded. Each space in the JS call *might* need to be encoded as `%20`, or removed as you suggested.

Comment: You're right about spaces on the web, I just wasn't sure if the browser auto-encoded spaces in the get request. (It does; I added a space in an image and the browser request was `GET /top%20part.jpg`) I guess it's up to your web server to do the decoding. Mine didn't and 404'd the image.